# Push a Flux using Spring Data with Reactive MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.2 and I'd like to insert the contents of a `Flux` into an array in a document in MongoDB using Spring Data its reactive mongodb support using [ReactiveMongoOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ReactiveMongoOperations.html). For example (Kotlin code):

```
val mongo : ReactiveMongoOperations = ...
data class Something(val data: String)
val flux = Flux.just(Something("A"), Something("B"))

mongo.upsert(query(where("_id").isEqualTo("myId")),
                        Update().push("myArray").each(flux),
                        "collection")
```

(note that this is just an example and `flux` is not generated using `Flux.just(..)` in the actual code).

While this works it doesn't yield the result I want:

```
{ "_id" : "myId", "myArray" : [ { "array" : [ { "data" : "A" }, { "data" : "B" } ], "_class" : "reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray" } ] }
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
{ "_id" : "myId", "myArray" : [ { "data" : "A" }, { "data" : "B" } ] }
```

i.e. that Spring Data serializes the content (elements) in the `Flux` and not the `Flux` itself. This example yields the correct result:

```
mongo.upsert(query(where("_id").isEqualTo("myId")),
                        Update().push("myArray").each(Something("A"), Something("B")),
                        "collection")
```

How can I achieve this *without blocking*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL; DR

You need to collect the items upfront and `$push` a collection of items.

## Explanation

You can't use reactive wrapper types as values of a MongoDB query as they are required to be resolved to values upfront. You can achieve what you want by applying `collectList()` and `flatMap()` operators:

```
val flux: Flux<Something>

flux.collectList()
    .flatMap { mongo.upsert(query(where("_id").isEqualTo("myId")),
                    Update().push("myArray").each(it),
                    "collection")  }
```

If the number of elements grows beyond a resonable limit, then `buffer(n)` might be the more appropriate choice.